# Finding last occurrence of space (' ') in a varchar column in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 10.5 and I am trying to write a query which can give me the last occurrence of space in a string in a varchar column. I tried using Locate function but didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you show us the exact syntax you've tried so far?

Comment: If DB2 supported a native REVERSE function, this would be fairly easy, but it doesn't.  You might have to write a UDF to handle this.

Comment: What is the overall scenario, could go provide details on why you search for the last space?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return *the position* of the last space in a string, you can use the [LOCATE_IN_STRING](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054098.html) function with a negative 'start' argument, for example:

```
values locate_in_string('Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party',' ',-1 )

1          
-----------
         59

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I also tried using INSTR function which worked too. Thank you very much.